# Concatenar e converter array string em int

Tags: c#

Não consigo juntar todos os números de um array, não estou falando em somar, mas sim concatenar, e converter em um inteiro. Veja o exemplo:

ex:

```
string[] matriz = new string[3];
matriz[0] = "2";
matriz[1] = "5";
matriz[2] = "0";
```

Quero juntar o numeral 2,5,0 em 250? O exemplo está usando uma array string, mas poderia ser um array de inteiros, isso não faz diferença para mim, desde que consiga concatená-los e colocar em um inteiro com o valor 250.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `Join` do objeto `String` pode ser útil.

Ele recebe como parâmetro:

- Um separador para o resultado final (no seu caso é uma `string` vazia já que quer unir tudo em uma `string` só);
- O `array`;
- O `index` inicial;
- O `index` final.

No seu caso ficaria:

```
var resultadoString = String.Join("", matriz, 0, matriz.Length);
```

depois basta pegar o `resultadoString` e parsear pra inteiro com o método `Parse` do tipo `int`:

```
var resultadoInt = int.Parse(resultadoString);
```

Fiz um fiddle mostrando como ficaria: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOvWYo

Answer (score 3):

Outra opção seria o método `Concat`

```
int result = int.Parse(string.Concat(matriz));
```

Vale lembrar que `new string[2]` faz com que o array tenha apenas 2 elementos (0 e 1)

Answer (score 2):

De uma forma mais 'matemática' você pode fazer assim:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] matriz = new int[3]; 
        matriz[0] = 2;
        matriz[1] = 5;
        matriz[2] = 0;

        int result = 0;
        for(int i = matriz.Length-1, j = 1; i >= 0; i--, j*=10)
        {
            result = result + (j * matriz[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no dotnetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmJZXj)

Como o valor final você quer que seja string, considero as outras respostas mais adequadas que a minha. Mas o `result` pode depois ser convertido facilmente utilizando o `ToString()`.

Observe que fiz algumas correções no seu código também.

1. Você estava atribuindo inteiros no na matriz[], mas ela era do tipo
   string.
2. Seu array só tinha 2 posições, mas você atribuía 3 posições.